# "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, props})."

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

While running the test for the below component, I get the error message `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, props}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead`

The above issue happens only when I use mount. With shallow it works.

```
import { createMock } from "ts-auto-mock";
interface Props {
  incidentId: string;
  errorMessage:JSX.Element;
  problemType:IncidentSummaryProblemTypeEnum;
}
describe("incidentdetails tests", () => {
  let mock : Props;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await Messages.init("en");
  });
      
  beforeEach(() => {
    mock = createMock<Props>();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it("test component incidentdetails", async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={mockConnectorStore}><IncidentDetails {...mock}/></Provider>);
      expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });
});
```

Below is the component

```
interface Props {
  incidentId: string;
  errorMessage:JSX.Element;
  problemType:IncidentSummaryProblemTypeEnum;
}
export const IncidentDetails: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
const render = (errorMessage : JSX.Element): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <>
        <ErrorPanel message={errorMessage || props.errorMessage} setDisableButton={setDisableButton}/>
        <DetailTemplate
          breadcrumbItems={breadCrumbs(problemType)}
          
        >
          <DetailContent
            
          />
        </DetailTemplate>
      </>
    );
  };
});
```

I don't see any issue on the console while the component is getting rendered on the browser. I see this issue only while running test

Comment: how does your mock looks like?

Comment: updated the question with mock details

Comment: Are you importing/exporting all of your components correctly? Check to make sure all use `export default` and are being imported from the correct file locations

Comment: In the test if I define the props errorMessage  as ```errorMessage:undefined``` instead of ```errorMessage:JSX.Element```, it works.

```interface Props {
  incidentId: string;
  errorMessage:undefined;
  problemType:IncidentSummaryProblemTypeEnum;
}```

Not sure whats wrong there?

Comment: I modified the props like below
```const props = {
  incidentId: "123",
  errorMessage: <div>errorMessage</div>,
  problemType:"TECH"
};```

and this seems to fix my issue. I still not sure why the previous way was throwing an error.